# SQL Server and Visual Studio dropdownlist "select from where" from another dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

So i have a program which adds pets to a database,

in this database have three tables: `pets`, `breeds`, `species`

When i add a pet i need to select a species using a dropdownlist `speciesDropDownList` , and then again select a breed from another dropdownlist `breedDropDownList`, however when i view the breed dropdownlist - it shows all breeds - not the breeds for the selected species from the previous dropdownlist

Question: How can i make the breed dropdownlist show only relevant breeds in relation to the previously selected species in species dropdownlist?

Example - when i select `Cat` from `speciesDropDownList`, i want `breedDropDownList` to show only `Persian`

[Screenshot of species dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfDz3.png)

[Screenshot of breed dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehIPL.png)

[Screenshot of both dropdownlists from inside visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ1hu.png)

[Screenshot showing both Breed and Species Tables data values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKWSw.png)

I am imagining a code such as:

```
SELECT BreedName FROM Breed WHERE Breed.Species = Species.Name
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: See following : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/cascading-combobox-in-windows-application-using-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have onChange event on your species dropdown to populate your breed dropdown..

This query should work -> SELECT BreedName FROM Breed WHERE Breed.Species = Species.Name